# Spring Boot Generic Request

Tags: generics, spring-boot

Can I create one request that receive one generic type?

I create one class Pedido

```
public class Pedido {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String protocolo;
    private Date entrada;
    private String observacao;
    private Date analise;
    private Date retirada;
    private Date validade;
    List<Andamento> andamento;
```

than I create 2 class

```
public class Prenotacao extends  Pedido{

    private String outorgante;
    private String outorgado;
    private String documentos;
    private BigDecimal deposito;
```

and

```
public class Certidao extends Pedido {
    private String teste;
```

I try to create this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pedido")
public class PedidoController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/")
    public Pedido insert(@RequestBody Pedido pedido){
        System.out.println("para para para");
        return pedido;
    }
}
```

but if I pass in my json the outorgante propertie or document in my controller I cant find this properties because the spring dont convert to Prenotacao or Certidao

how can I fix this?

tks

Comment: how are you passing the json data and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please add JSON Request Data as example